# How to start a Python app from the Windows 10 IoT remote Powershell terminal?

Tags: python, windows-iot

I have deployed and successfully run a Python app from VS2015 on my Raspberry Pi Win 10 IoT, however, I cannot figure out how to start the Python app when remoted in to the computer via Powershell.

I am ultimately trying to use the scheduled tasks command, schtasks.exe, which is supported on Windows 10 IoT to periodically start up the Python app.

PS. I know I could put my App asleep and wake up once in a while to achieve the same behavior, but I would like to understand more how apps are run on Win IoT.

Comment: It seems to be installing the application in some kind of Windows 8 phone way, as an app container... I searched most of the directories for the app but couldn't find it. I copied over my app bin directory and tried to run that directly, and gave me a container issue. The scheduled task requires the path to the app... which is untraceable at the moment. There must be a way because the WebGui can do it.. but I cant find the source code to the webgui... so nice of MS. Will keep trying to find an answer. Running a console app will be OK direct as exe.. but how to start the package....

Comment: thanks, I agree with your findings. I saw essentially the same. If there is a way, I hope Microsoft can add it to their documentation.